# No import for existing contact

Tags: import, duplicate-contacts

When doing an import for existing contact that I want to update, after selecting Fill (For Duplicate Contacts), I get a Warning, a Notice but no import :

```
    Warning: array_pop() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in CRM_Contact_Import_Parser_Contact->import() (line 706 of /var/data/sites/sitename/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contact/Import/Parser/Contact.php).
    Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in CRM_Contact_Import_ImportJob->_addImportedContactsToNewGroup() (line 393 of /var/data/sites/sitename/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contact/Import/ImportJob.php).
```

There is a Warning and a Notice for each contact submitted.

The Dedupe Rule is selected to Email
The version of CiviCRM is 4.7.22

I have a feeling that something is corrupted in the database.

Thanks for your help.

Regards.

Ichi

Comment: One good way to verify this would be to use some sample data to replicate the process on the Demo site eg dmaster.demo.civicrm.org